# I login and send a secure cookie to browser. Now on http page if I make a request can it send the secure cookie accross?

Tags: security, cookies, https

Does the browser send a secure cookie over http connection. I have a website where some pages are https some are http. I create a secure cookie over a http page. Now if I move to a http page and refresh the http page will the cookie be sent to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies with the secure attribute are only send with https requests/webpages.

But warning : if you mix http and https webpages, nothing prevent an attacker to display a fake login page on your http webpage. The only secure way to avoid this is to always use https and activate HSTS.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how your page will be loaded if you use secure attribute over http call since cookie will be sent to https call only.  reference : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag